# Redraw View Android

Tags: android, view

I now have a View that is added programically after the onCreate (Depending on some other variables). Everything works as it should and it draws part of a circle.

But my question is how do i redraw it later on ? I need to change the angle in the circle after some data is fetched.

Code for the WindRose :

```
    public class WindRose extends View {

    public WindRose(Context context) {
        super(context);


    }

    @Override

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvasTest = canvas;


        float height = (float) getHeight();
        float width = (float) getWidth();

        float radius;

        if (width > height) {
            radius = height / 2;

        } else {
            radius = width / 2;
        }

        // radius = (height )/ 2;


        Path path = new Path();
        path.addCircle(width, height, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);

        // / 2

        Resources resources = getResources();
        int color = resources.getColor(R.color.green_back);



        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        float center_x, center_y;
        center_x = width / 2;
        center_y = height / 2;



        //Formulas :
        //SD = Start Degree
        //ED = End Degree

        //If cakepiece passes 0 (East)
        //SD, 360-(SD+ED)

        //Else :
        //SD, (ED-SD)

        oval.set(center_x - radius, center_y - radius, center_x + radius, center_y + radius);

        if (End > Start) {
            canvas.drawArc(oval, Start, (End - Start), true, paint);

        } else if (End < Start) {
            canvas.drawArc(oval, Start, ((360 - Start) + End), true, paint);
        }


    }


}
```

If i update the `Start` and `End` variables nothing happens. i have also tried to call `invalidate` on the class but also there i dont get any redrawing.

Invalidate that i've tried :

```
WindRose windrose = new WindRose(this);
windrose.invalidate();
```

Was called from the main class which WindRose is part of.

How should i do this correctly ?

Comment: I just saw, that you've written, that invalidate does not help. Can you verify, that the onDraw() method is/isn't called after you call invalidate?

Comment: But from this code snippet it seems you create a new View and call invalidate on it and not on the one that you already have drawn in onCreate(). Was this just in order to show how you call invalidate, or do you call it exactly like this?

Comment: I can via debugging confirm the the OnDraw() is not called after invalidate. Only called onCreate

Comment: You got a very good point. I vas creating a new View and then invalidating it..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe calling the `invalidate()` method of the view will help.

You can read more here(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), but:
"To force a view to draw, call invalidate()."

Note, also that you can invalidate only parts of a view